# How can I use radio button where each button is dedicated to one array value?

Tags: html, arrays, forms, button, radio-button

So what I am trying to do is create a radio button of, say 5 options. Because it's a radio button, obviously only one option can be selected. I want this array button to insert five values to an array where the selected gives the value of 1, and the others 0.

Let's say I have five options: A, B, C, D, E

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">A<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">B<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">C<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">D<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">E<br>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If select option B, how can I put it in an array so that it equals [0,1,0,0,0].
Is there a simple way to do this?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add an eventListener to the form submit
2. cast a querySelectorAll to array and map the truthyness of the checked attribute

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove if you want the form to submit
  const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=fav_language]")]
    .map(rad => +rad.checked);
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">A<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">B<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">C<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">D<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">E<br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an onSubmit function to the form which gets executed when the button is pressed. The function then assigns the values in the array according to the option selected by the user.

```js
let arr = [];
const createArray = (e) => {
  radios = document.getElementsByName("fav_language");
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    arr[i] = +radios[i].checked;
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="createArray()">
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">A<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">B<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">C<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">D<br>
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="1">E<br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you use const and let, why not use let in the for loop?

Comment: Ah, you changed your if to my unary plus version :) Simpler than a ternary too and much better than your if

Comment: Yupp xD. I was in a hurry to answer this so missed that part. Your answer is much cleaner lol

Comment: I do however not recommend inline onsubmit.

Comment: Why do you not recommend that?

Comment: If you want to stop submission with an inline onsubmit, you need to use onsubmit="return createArray()" and return false in the function

Comment: Oh i didnt know that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: inline event handlers are discouraged. They are very easy to overwrite and do not adhere to the separation of concerns

Comment: Ohh i didnt know that. thanks